# node js web app on AWS failed to lookup failed to lookup view "pages/home" in views directory "/var/app/views"

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to put my simple node js web app on AWS EB but it seems like it has a problem with path. I'm running windows on my machine and it works but when I deploy it on EB it gives me the following error

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "pages/home" in views directory "/var/app/views"
   at EventEmitter.render (/var/app/current/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:579:17)
   at ServerResponse.render (/var/app/current/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:961:7)
   at null.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/controller/app.js:113:14)
   at tryCatcher (/var/app/current/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
   at Promise.successAdapter [as _fulfillmentHandler0] (/var/app/current/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/nodeify.js:23:30)
   at Promise._settlePromise (/var/app/current/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:557:21)
   at Promise._settlePromise0 (/var/app/current/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:605:10)
   at Promise._settlePromises (/var/app/current/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:684:18)
   at Async._drainQueue (/var/app/current/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:126:16)
   at Async._drainQueues (/var/app/current/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:136:10)
   at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/var/app/current/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:16:14)
   at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

my code for path

```
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('../public')));

app.set('views',path.resolve('../views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Comment: have you got some code showing how you're trying to load the views?

Comment: code added. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the **path** module to resolve directory and file names (to avoid issues with the differences between Windows and linux filesystems).

It could be a file permissions or ownership issue. Check that the user under which the node process is running has read permissions on the relevant directories and files.

It could also be a path resolution issue. It looks like your app is in **/var/app/current/**, but you're trying to find files in **/var/app/views/**. Should work if that's how your app is structured, but it would be problematic if you intended to look for files in **/var/app/current/views/**.

Comment: I have added some code on my question. I don't think it has something to do with permission because I'm deploying it to AWS EB. I'm running on windows and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just concentrate on case sensitivity.  Ensure that the filename passed on the render is exactly the same as the file on the server ...

eg.
res.render("Challenge",... having a view filename challenge.hbs... WILL FAIL
res.render("challenge",... having a view filename challenge.hbs... WILL PASS

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, my problem is that I forget to zip the view sub directory in my root directory recursively, thus resulting in a empty view directory when deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. So when packing your code you should use something like `zip -r example.zip .` .